# Make Byte array To File for download Using ajax

Tags: javascript, java

Now i'm trying to make a file download with ajax but when i open downloaded file, picture viewer said this file format is not supported
how can i fix it?

it is javascript part

```
    function downloadFile(file_no){
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("POST","/timewizard/file/download/"+file_no);
        xhr.send();
        xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200){
                if (xhr.responseText != null && xhr.responseText  != "" && xhr.responseText != '[]'){
                    let item = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                    console.log(item);
                    let bytes = new Uint8Array(item.bytes.length);
                    let length = bytes.length;
                    for (let i = 0; i < length; i++){
                        bytes[i] = item.bytes.charCodeAt(i);
                    }
                    // let blob = new Blob([item.bytes], {type: item.mime});
                    let blob = new Blob(bytes, {type: item.mime});
                    console.log(blob);
                    let link = document.createElement("a");
                    link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                    let fileName = "timewizard_" + new Date().getTime();
                    link.download = fileName + "." + item.extension;
                    link.click();
                    // return xhr.responseText;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and java class file part

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/download/{file_no}")
//  public byte[] fileDownload(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, @PathVariable int file_no) {
    public Map<String, Object> fileDownload(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, @PathVariable int file_no) {
        Map<String, Object> answer = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        
        FileUploadDto dto = fileUploadBiz.selectOne(file_no);
        String extension = FilenameUtils.getExtension(dto.getFile_name());
        String mime_front = (dto.getFile_type().equals("P"))?"image":"video";
        String mime_back = (extension.toLowerCase().equals("jpg"))?"jpeg":extension.toLowerCase();
        answer.put("mime", mime_front + "/" + mime_back);
        answer.put("extension", extension);
        
        byte[] down = null;
        
        try {
            String uploadPath = WebUtils.getRealPath(request.getSession().getServletContext(), "/resources/image");
            File file = new File(uploadPath + "/" + dto.getFile_name());
            
            down = FileCopyUtils.copyToByteArray(file);
            String filename = new String(file.getName().getBytes(), "8859_1");
            
//          response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\""+filename +"\"");
            
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        answer.put("bytes", down);

//      return down;
        return answer;
        
    }
```

The commented part was a method of creating a form and submit button in html and directly spread?returning a byte array, and it actually works nice.
but I want to use a blob.
is there any idea for using blob? or other nice one?
Thanks!

Comment: I don't think you should be using ajax and blobs. Content-Disposition is a much better way to download files

Comment: @Endless First of all, thanks to your answer! Can you give me a explain why Content-Disposition is much better way then using ajax and blobs? (safety? or what?) Or can you recommend any blog post or something?

Comment: 1) you get a native browser UI for progress. 2) you can pause, resume cancel & retry the download from the download history. 3) don't have to buffer up the file in RAM memory. - can download really large files - so won't crash the browser for large +500mb files. 4) better cross browser compatibility. 5) Don't need any client side javascript - works with js turned off. 6) Doing `link.click()` without user interaction (eg async callback) might cause a popup block. 7) you can download the file in background - meaning you can close/reload the tab or navigate to another url